# When the inverse of bounded linear operator equal to its adjoint operator in Hilbert $(A^{-1} = A^*)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

If we have the bounded linear operator from Hilbert space H to H, when we will know that the inverse of A is the adjoint operator of A ($A^{-1}=A^*$) or there are any situation which make they are coincide. I try to think about the mapping $ A: x \rightarrow <x,e_i>_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ but I still cannot figure out how to show $A^{-1}=A^*$.

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to $AA^*=A^*A=I$, which implies that $A$ is unitary.

Answer (score 2):

Such an operator is called Unitary. A sufficient condition is that

1. $A$ is surjective (in fact dense image is enough)
2. $A$ preserves the inner product on $H$: $$\langle Ax, Ay\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$$

Many examples come from the following situation. Let $B:H\to H$ be a self adjoint operator on $H$, that is $B^*=B$ and $Dom(B)=Dom(B^*)$, and define

$$A = e^{iB}\ .$$

Then $A$ is unitary.